# Data model - PRIMARY KEY numbering issue

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-relationship

I have the following issue:

I have this entity, let's call it `ENTITY_THREE`, which is part of a <strike>arc</strike> **barred relationship**:

Three entities `ENTITY_ONE`, `ENTITY_TWO` and `ENTITY_THREE` which are part of an <strike>arc</strike> **barred relationship**

[image]

Please note that `ENTITY_THREE` has a composite primary key: `ID`, `ID_OF_ONE`, `ID_OF_TWO` and `ENTITY_TWO` has a composite primary key as well: `ID`, `ID_OF_ONE`.

Now, according to the description of the assignment, if `ENTITY_TWO` has more than 1 of `ENTITY_THREE`, `ENTITY_THREE` needs to be numbered by `ENTITY_TWO`, like so:

*ENTITY TWO:*

```
ID
1
2
```

*ENTITY THREE:*

```
ID  ID_OF_TWO
1   1
2   1
3   1
1   2
2   2
3   2
```

So, what I basically want is that when you use an **INSERT** statement, you must not provide the `ID`: it adds it for you automatically. But the `ID` is numbered by a **foreign key**: all records with an `ID_OF_TWO` 1, let's say 5, will be numbered 1 through 5, all records with an `ID_OF_TWO` 2, let's say 3, will be numbered 1 through 3, and so on …

Is there any way (a **TRIGGER** maybe?) I can accomplish this?

**@EDIT:**
Earlier on I talked about an **arc relationship**, but what I actually mean't was a **barred relationship**, my bad.

**@Update:**
I saw something a couple of days ago that might work, but I'm not too sure. I'm going to try it anyways. I will let you guys know if it worked or not …

Comment: Can you tell us the order in which you see these records being inserted?

Comment: I don't understand. There are three tables **E1** (e1_id, ...), **E2** (e2_id, e1_id, ...), and **E3** (e3_id, e2_id, ...). So yes, the content for the entity 3 table may look like you are showing. And now you want to know what exactly?

Comment: Well, I want to use something so when you use an INSERT statement, you must not provide the ID, but the ID will be inserted automatically. But you have to consider the foreign key: all records with an ID_OF_TWO 1, let's say 5, will be numbered 1 through 5, all records with an ID_OF_TWO 2, let's say 3, will be numbered 1 through 3, and so on …

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't read carefully. A column called `ID` should always be the table's ID, uniquely identifying a record. This is not the case in your example. You are looking for composite keys, where a record in E3 is identified by e2_id plus a running number which you want generated. This doesn't match the diagram and is quite complicated to achieve.

Comment: Yeah, this ERD is just a quick draft, but the entity that is called ENTITY_THREE here, has a composite primary key in my actual implementation …

Comment: I don't see any arcs in your ERD, and it seems to be missing the IDs you say are relevant to the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean't barred, not arc …