# Check constraint for multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

The teacher gave us a team assignment, and me and my teammate are quite struggling with it (especially since we need to use things like **TRIGGERS** and **PROCEDURES**, things we didn't see in class yet …).

We need to implement an **arc-relationship**, and we fail to understand how …
But before I tell you guys what I need to accomplish, I will give you part of the description of the task, so you guys can understand the situation a bit better …

We basically need to make an ERD for a **VLSI CAD-system** and we need to implement it. Now, we have our `CELL` entity, the attributes of which aren't really relevant … The only thing you guys need to know in order to help us is that it has a **primary key**, `CELL_CODE`, which is a **VARCHAR**.

Each `CELL` has many (I think at least four, I don't think you can have triangular `CELLS`, but doesn't matter anyways) `SIDES`. A `SIDE` can be logically identified by its `CELL`, and to make matters ridiculously difficult, each `SIDE` has to be numbered by its `CELL`, like so:

*CELLS:*

```
CELL_CODE
1
2
```

*SIDES:*

```
SEQUENCE_NUMBER  CELL_CODE
1                1
2                1
3                1
1                2
2                2
3                2
```

Now, each `SIDE` has its `CONNECTION_PINS`. `CONNECTION_PINS` is also uniquely identified by `SIDES`, which are basically numbered in a similar manner:

*CELLS:*

```
CELL_CODE
1
2
```

*SIDES:*

```
SEQUENCE_NUMBER  CELL_CODE
1                1
2                1
3                1
1                2
2                2
3                2
```

*CONNECTION_PINS:*

```
SEQUENCE_NUMBER  SIE_SEQUENCE_NUMBER  CELL_CODE
1                1                    1
2                1                    1
1                2                    1
2                2                    1
1                3                    1
2                3                    1
1                1                    2
2                1                    2
1                2                    2
2                2                    2
1                3                    2
2                3                    2
```

I tried to explain the numbering issue we have here: [Data model - PRIMARY KEY numbering issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50486727/data-model-primary-key-numbering-issue?noredirect=1#comment88058709_50486727), but yeah, I didn't really explain it the way it should be explained ...

Now, we have one final entity, which is where the **Arc** comes in: `CONNECTIONS`. `CONNECTIONS` has 2 `CONNECTION_PINS`: one for `START_FROM`and one for `END_OF`. Now, logically seen the start pin can't be the end pin as well, for a given connection. And that's our struggle. Basically, this shouldn't be allowed:

*CELLS:*

```
CELL_CODE
1
2
```

*SIDES:*

```
SEQUENCE_NUMBER  CELL_CODE
1                1
2                1
3                1
1                2
2                2
3                2
```

*CONNECTION_PINS:*

```
SEQUENCE_NUMBER  SIE_SEQUENCE_NUMBER  CELL_CODE
1                1                    1
2                1                    1
1                2                    1
2                2                    1
1                3                    1
2                3                    1
1                1                    2
2                1                    2
1                2                    2
2                2                    2
1                3                    2
2                3                    2
```

*CONNECTIONS:*
(you shouldn't be able to put this in …)

```
CPI_SEQNUM_START  SIE_SEQNUM_START  CELL_CODE_START  CPI_SEQNUM_END  SIE_SEQNUM_END  CELL_CODE_END
1                 1                 1                1               1               1
```

Now, this is basically the ERD for this part:

[ERD with barred relationships and the arc-relationship in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SizoE.png)

and this is the physical model:

[Physical model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCARR.png)

I basically thought a simple **CHECK** might do (CHECK (`CPI_SEQNUM_START` <> `CPI_SEQNUM_END` AND `CELL_CODE_START` <> `CELL_CODE_END` AND `SIE_SEQNUM_START` <> `SIE_SEQNUM_END`) ), but that prevented us from inserting anything somehow … Any advice?

Comment: What have u done so far for your assignment?

Comment: Basically every CREATE and ALTER TABLE statement, with the exception of the numbering thing for the entities of the barred relationship (since they have that special numbering), most INSERT statements written, a little bit of testing, and that's about it.

Comment: And oh yeah, I have triggers for the primary keys of other entities, so I don't need to specify them at INSERT (which makes use of a sequence).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach was correct to use a `CHECK` constraint.  Your logic for the constraint was wrong though.  You need an `OR` condition.  Only one of the three fields needs to be different.

```
CPI_SEQNUM_START <> CPI_SEQNUM_END OR
CELL_CODE_START <> CELL_CODE_END OR
SIE_SEQNUM_START <> SIE_SEQNUM
```

... assuming all three fields are not nullable.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see … My CHECK could never work. How stupid of me! I thought like: it needs to be the connection_pin of a specific side and of a specific cell, so it needs to be AND that cell_code AND that sie_number AND that connection_pin for both start and end, otherwise we aren't talking about the same cell … Maybe that's why I mistakenly used AND instead of OR …